# PSD - Spectrum analysis

Tags: fft, stft, power-spectral-density

Could someone tell me where it is that I might be going wrong with the following problem?

Ok, so I'm computing a spectrogram, and, trying to return the PDS of the signal (to show where the signal has the most energies) which I will then use in plotting the decibels.

In my approach, I multiply each of the frames by the Hanning window, perform FFT of the resulting blocks and then only take the first half of the result (resulting vector).

Finally, I take each of the blocks (computed by the STFT) and perform PSD.

The problem that I'm having is this:

The chart below illustrates the results that I'm getting using my own `C++` code:

[image]

Whereas in `Python`, using `matplotlib` if I replicate this, then I get the following:

[image]

I can't understand where the "noise" is coming from. I can only think that it could be some periodic noise which could be due to little discontinuities at the start and at the end of each frame. But I don't know where I have gone wrong.

The `NFFT = 256` hop size = `128`

Thanks

Comment: Anyone? =) any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hello, and wellcome to DSP. We discourage asking questions directly about programming code, writing new code or debugging. I tried to focus your question on the _approach_ and your _results_. Feel free to add more detail. I feel the question is more focused on what the community here is interested this way.

Comment: @penelope I thought with having the code, it would be a lot easier for someone to debug, since, this question does not seem to be getting any responses

Comment: Well, the python implementations are open source. Reading the code and comparing with yours should tell you what is different.

Comment: It's true that it'd help us debug, but the thing of the matter is, we _don't deal with code_ here. This is not the right site if you want something _debugged_ (you go to stackoverflow for that). We, here, can help you with (finding a flaw in) your _approach_: you should elaborate on that, explain what results you are expecting (and why) and where they differ from what you have.

Comment: @jan That is the thing, they are the same? Kind of, the only thing that changes is from python to C++ but I can't seem to find the C++ code for it the python implementation, since all of the pythonscripts are created in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by this statement given the previous one indicates you've already taken the FFT.

> Finally, I take each of the blocks (computed by the STFT) and perform PSD.

Generally the following is used; Seperate into frames (overlap if desired) -> apply window -> fft -> transform and scale into dB (if desired).

The scaling for a power spectrum or power spectral density can be a bit tricky at first, but this [paper](http://www.rssd.esa.int/SP/LISAPATHFINDER/docs/Data_Analysis/GH_FFT.pdf) goes into some great detail about how to set it up.

Comment: @proten - the paper looks quite interesting and relevant . do you have to take the Fourier transform of the window and calculate the sum in order to calculate the PSD?

Comment: You would take the FFT of Data*Window. If you are referring to summing the window values or the square of the window values, that is for normalization. Have a look at section 12 if you're still unsure of the process.